# .xxxxxx ?? v.Outer.Outer.xxxx)' could not be translated OrderByDescending with null conditional asp.net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

```
    public virtual DateTime? LastModificationTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
```

Query

```
await vulnerabilityMappingSelect
      .OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModificationTime ?? x.CreationTime)
      .PageBy(input).ToListAsync();
```

Trying to filter if `LastModificationTime` has value then sort with `LastModificationTime` otherwise sort with `CreationTime`

Getting an exception as could not be translated as below

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<VulnerabilityMappingTemplate>()
    .Where(v => __ef_filter__p_0 || !(((ISoftDelete)v).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_1 || (int?)((IMustHaveTenant)v).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_2)
    .Where(v => v.TenantId == __AbpSession_TenantId_Value_0)
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<SourceType>()
            .Where(s => __ef_filter__p_3 || !(((ISoftDelete)s).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_4 || ((IMayHaveTenant)s).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_5), 
        outerKeySelector: v => EF.Property<int?>(v, "SourceTypeId"), 
        innerKeySelector: s => EF.Property<int?>(s, "Id"), 
        resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<VulnerabilityMappingTemplate, SourceType>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<SourceTool>()
            .Where(s0 => __ef_filter__p_6 || !(((ISoftDelete)s0).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_7 || ((IMayHaveTenant)s0).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_8), 
        outerKeySelector: v => EF.Property<int?>(v.Outer, "SourceToolId"), 
        innerKeySelector: s0 => EF.Property<int?>(s0, "Id"), 
        resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<VulnerabilityMappingTemplate, SourceType>, SourceTool>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .OrderByDescending(v => new VulnerabilityMappingTemplate{ 
        Id = v.Outer.Outer.Id, 
        TemplateName = v.Outer.Outer.TemplateName, 
        SourceType = v.Outer.Inner, 
        SourceTool = v.Inner, 
        VulnerabilityFieldMapping = MaterializeCollectionNavigation(
            Navigation: VulnerabilityMappingTemplate.VulnerabilityFieldMapping,
            subquery: DbSet<VulnerabilityFieldMapping>()
                .Where(v0 => __ef_filter__p_9 || !(((ISoftDelete)v0).IsDeleted) && __ef_filter__p_10 || (int?)((IMustHaveTenant)v0).TenantId == __ef_filter__CurrentTenantId_11)
                .Where(v0 => EF.Property<long?>(v.Outer.Outer, "Id") != null && object.Equals(
                    objA: (object)EF.Property<long?>(v.Outer.Outer, "Id"), 
                    objB: (object)EF.Property<long?>(v0, "VulnerabilityMappingTemplateId")))), 
        LastModifierUserId = v.Outer.Outer.LastModifierUserId, 
        CreatorUserId = v.Outer.Outer.CreatorUserId, 
        CreationTime = v.Outer.Outer.CreationTime 
    }
    .LastModificationTime ?? v.Outer.Outer.CreationTime)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Yes, makes sense. It can't order by x.LastModificationTime and  x.CreationTime in the same time when  x.LastModificationTime  is NULL. If you want order by LastModificationTime than by CreationTime. How would you write a SQL statement to have such order in the same time?

Comment: @DA I want to sort by LastModificationTime  if it has value otherwise sort by CreationTime

Comment: @DA what OP is ultimately asking is how to write in EF an SQL similar to SQL Server's `ORDER BY ISNULL(LastModificationTime, CreationTime)`

Comment: Have you tried? `.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastModificationTime == null? x.CreationTime: x.LastModificationTime)`

Comment: @Cleptus yes the same issue

Comment: @DA I have tried this way as well await vulnerabilityMappingSelect
                        .OrderByDescending( x => x.LastModificationTime != null)
                        .ThenByDescending(x=> x.CreationTime)
                        .PageBy(input).ToListAsync(); but still the same result

Comment: I see now the problem. The last option I am thinking is to split the query into 2 and use union to merge the 2 sorted results. A query for when LastModificationTime  is null and and the other one when LastModificationTime  is not null...

Comment: Have you tried to execute query without OrderBy? Query is complex but you have hidden almost everything in question.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes I have executed the query without orderby as well as with not nullable property, it works fine. The issue I am getting is with only nullable property

Comment: Well, I see your problem `LastModificationTime` has no defined projection. You have missed it in initialization of `VulnerabilityMappingTemplate`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You are a legend, perfect answer. Thank you so much. Can you please post your answer so that I can mark as true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem that `LastModificationTime` has no defined projection. You have missed it in initialization of `VulnerabilityMappingTemplate`.